# С прописной или строчной?

Tags: прописная-строчная

Word-документ

Answer (score 6):

Вряд ли в правилах русской орфографии есть регламентации для слов, написанных буквами нерусского алфавита. Мне кажется, написание с прописной буквы встречается гораздо чаще.